# Using PostgreSQL, how do I find all records that have the jsonb column filled out?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql, hstore, jsonb

Let's say I have a jsonb column type called "data" for the table "recipes". I'm trying to find all records that have "data" filled out (i.e. "data" is not null or an empty bracket {}).

I know for hstore columns, using ruby, you can use a query like this to do so:

```
Recipe.where("data <> ''")
```

Is there an equivalent query for jsonb?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updated after reading the question properly:

You can check for columns with NO data like this

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE json_column IS NOT NULL
```

So this would then be

```
Recipe.where.not('data IS NULL')
```

And for columns with non-empty hashes like this:

SELECT * FROM table WHERE json_column <> '{}'

This translates to:

```
Recipe.where('data <> ?', '{}')
# or
Recipe.where("data <> '{}'")
```

A good way to verify your query is to run them in SQL first (so you avoid AR and its translation of Ruby to SQL). Then you can try and build the query in AR and use `to_sql` to see what AR makes of your queries.

```
Recipe.where('data <> ?', '{}').to_sql
#=> "SELECT \"recipies\".* FROM \"recipies\" WHERE (data <> '{}')"
```

vs.

```
Recipe.where('data <> ?', {}).to_sql
#=> "SELECT \"recipies\".* FROM \"recipies\" WHERE (data <> NULL)"
```

Comment: Hi Pascal. Yes, I tried that but it's collecting recipes where there are empty brackets {}. This is the line I used specifically: 

Recipe.where.not('data IS NULL').map{|x|x.data}, 

and it's returning items with empty brackets like so: [{}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {"abc"=> "123"}, {}]

Comment: Hello sjsc i've updated the answer. Did not read the question properly:-(

Comment: Hi Pascal. I'm still not getting it unfortunately :-( When I try Recipe.where('data <> ?', {}), I get no returned records even though some of my entries contain non-empty hashes. (I'm using Rails 4.2.6, postgresql 9.5, and ruby 2.3.0.)

Comment: Hello sjsc please check again. I updated the answer.

Comment: Awesome solution Pascal!!! The "Recipe.where('data <> ?', '{}')" is perfect.  Thanks for the great explanation and thank you so much!!

Comment: Glad it helped. Thanks for the feedback!